# CellForRowAt not called when adding TableView Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a UI (programmatically) that will show two main parts

- The first part will show a video Player
- The second part will show a UITableView with more videos

I have successfully worked on the first part, it's working and it's occupying a small portion of the screen at the top

Using the same logic I tried to add a UITableView in the main Container View, but all I can see is an empty tableView

I also tried to log messages when cellForRowAt will be called, but nothing is printed , I concluded that the cellForRowAt is not being called

Here's the code of the class that does all of this :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class VideoLauncher: NSObject , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


let data : [String] =  ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4"]

// TableView initialization
let tableView : UITableView = {
    let t  = UITableView()
    t.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    t.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
    t.rowHeight = 80

    return t
}()


func showVideoPlayer(){
    
    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
      
        // View Container that will contain the player and the tableview
        let mainContainer = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
        mainContainer.backgroundColor = .white
        mainContainer.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 30, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 30, width: 10, height: 10)
      
        // Creating and adding the first part : PlayerView
        let height = keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16
        let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)
        let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
        mainContainer.addSubview(videoPlayerView)
        
        
        // Creating and adding the second Part: TableView
        // I'm adding the tableView to another UIView : tableViewContainer
       
        let tableViewContainer = UIView()
           tableViewContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: videoPlayerView.frame.maxY, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
     
        mainContainer.addSubview(tableViewContainer)
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableViewContainer.frame.width, height: tableViewContainer.frame.height)
        
        tableViewContainer.addSubview(tableView)

        keyWindow.addSubview(mainContainer)
          
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            mainContainer.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.minX, y: keyWindow.frame.minY + 35, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)
        } completion: { (Bool) in
          
        }
    
    }
}

// MARK: - TABLEVIEW DATA SOURCE

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("NumberOfRows In Section")
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Cell For row At")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath)
    let s = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = s
    return cell
}
}
```

And all I get as output is this :

[image]

**----- EDIT ------** 
Based on different suggestions that I received in the comment section , I modified my code a little bit, I anchored the tableView to its container and called tableView.reloadData() When the animation is completed.

As a result, CellForRowAt is called once, and cells are shown but disappear as quickly as they appear.

Below is the modified version of my previous code

```
class VideoLauncher: NSObject , UITableViewDataSource{
  
    
    let data : [String] =  ["String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4", "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 4"]
    
    // TableView initialization
    let tableView : UITableView = {
        let t  = UITableView()
        t.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        return t
    }()
    

    func showVideoPlayer(){
        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
          
            // View Container that will contain the player and the tableview
            let mainContainer = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            mainContainer.backgroundColor = .white
            mainContainer.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.width - 30, y: keyWindow.frame.height - 30, width: 10, height: 10)
            
        
            // Creating and adding the first part : PlayerView
            let height = keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16
            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            mainContainer.addSubview(videoPlayerView)
            
        
            // Creating and adding the second Part: TableView
            // I'm adding the tableView to another UIView : customView
            let tableViewContainer = UIView()
            tableViewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              
            mainContainer.addSubview(tableViewContainer)
            tableViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoPlayerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableViewContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            tableViewContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            
            tableViewContainer.addSubview(self.tableView)
            self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            self.tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            self.tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
           
            keyWindow.addSubview(mainContainer)
            
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.5,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                options: .curveEaseOut) {

                mainContainer.frame = CGRect(x: keyWindow.frame.minX, y: keyWindow.frame.minY + 35, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

                } completion: { (Bool) in

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: - TABLEVIEW DATA SOURCE
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("NumberOfRows In Section")
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("Cell For row At")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath)
        let s = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = s
        return cell
    }
 }
```

And what I really get as output is this

[image]

What could be the cause of the behaviour of the TableView  ?

Comment: use heightforrow method and set height to 200 for now and check cellforrow called or not okay.

Comment: @YogeshPatel I've added HeightForRowAt, this method too is not being called

Comment: You have set `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`,  but you are not using autolayout. Either use autolayout (recommended) or set this properly to `true` (the default) and continue to set the frame directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you recheck my updated question?

Comment: I think the problem may be because you are still combining autolayout and setting the frame of your video,player directly. You should use one approach or the other. Also, and this won't fix your problem, you should use leading anchor and trailing anchor rather than left/right to handle RTL locales correctly.